# How do I fix a font compatibilty issue from Mac to Windows, using Adobe Flash CS4?

Tags: windows, flash, macos, fonts

I need to edit a Flash movie that somebody else developed in Adobe Flash CS3 on a Mac. I'm using Adobe Flash CS4 on Windows (Vista). However, the font that shows up on my computer is much bigger than on the .SWF that he produced.

He used a custom font, which I had to add to my system Fonts folder. Because Adobe Flash now detects the right fonts on my computer (because I installed them), it doesn't map them to substitute fonts.

I believe the fonts are being rendered differently because I'm using Windows.

Does anybody have a clue why they would be rendering differently? How do I fix this?

EDIT: If it has any significance, the missing fonts were: "Univers LT Std 57 Condensed" and "Univers LT Std 57 Condensed Oblique"

Answer (score 0):

Did you open the font mapping settings to make sure that Flash is mapping the font in the FLA to the font you want used? (Under Edit > Font Mapping.)

Comment: Yes. Adobe Flash doesn't have any missing fonts for the FLA file because I installed the ones that were previously missing in Control Panel > Fonts. The list-box under Edit > Font Mapping is empty.